# Why does connecting pdb with different services in tnsora produce different databases?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, pdb, oracle19c

I was experimenting with the oracle 19c dB and while creating a pdb from a cdb.

I have 2 services in tnsora file. I created tables for pdb with service1. Why is it that connecting to service1 and creating a table, I cannot view the any tables from connecting to service2? In my connection tab,my hostname, username and PW in SQL developer are the same but only difference is the service name.

Here is tnsora:

```
SERVICE1 =
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = SERVICE1)
    )
  )

SERVICE2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = SERVICE2)
    )
  )
```

Comment: The only reason I can think of would be that service2 is pointing to a different PDB. What does `lsnrctl status` show on the server? What's in your client's tnsnames.ora file?

Comment: When connected to the database, execute `select * from global_name;` to see which database you are connected to.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for replies. After checking, it seems that I mistaken different account users as PDBs so i was logging in user1 into service1 and user1 into service2 and comparing them.  In https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF268 , net_service_name is the database- am I wrong? Anyways, i think I've gotten the answer. Thanks again.